# Speed up Value function Iterations in Julia

Tags: loops, julia

I am coding a simple value function iteration in Julia. I posted the code below.

```
# ................................
# Solving the model
function Solver(P,uf,hf)
    @unpack r, σrisk, ρ, η, β, θ, nx, m, μ, fhat, ub, lb, tol, maxite, ne = P;
    # ..................................................
    # Tauchen discretization
    ly, Π = mytauch(μ, ρ, η, nx, m); # it is a tauchen discretization
    # ..................................................
    # states
    y = exp.(ly);
    b = [LinRange(lb,ub, ne)...];
    yb = b .+ y';
    p0 = findfirst(x-> x ==0, b);
    uhy = uf.(hf(y, fhat));

    # ..................................................
    # Initial guess for value functions
    vr0 = 1 / (1 - β) * uf.((r / (1 + r)) * b .+ y');
    vd0 = (1 / (1 - β) * uhy)';

    myup(vr,vd) =  updateVF(vr, vd, b, yb, uhy, Π, p0, uf, P);
    # ..................................................
    # Convergence algorithm
    dif = 1
    ite = 1
    vr1, vd1, bopt = (nothing,nothing, nothing);
    while dif>tol && ite < maxite
        vr1, bopt, vd1 = myup(vr0,vd0)
        dif = max(maximum(abs.(vr1-vr0)), maximum(abs.(vd1-vd0)));
        ite+=1;
        vr0, vd0 = (vr1, vd1);
    end
    # ..................................................
    # Policies functions
    vf1, D, δ, q = postVR(vr1,vd1,Π,r)
    #bb = repeat(b,1,nx);
    vd1 = repeat(vd1,ne,1);
    bprime = b[bopt];
    PolFun = (vf=vf1 , vr=vr1, vd=vd1, bprime = bprime, q=q,D=D, δ=δ);
    out2 = (b= b, y= y,ydef=hf(y, fhat),Π=Π, uhy = uhy, p0 = p0);
    return PolFun, out2;
end

function updateVF(vr0, vd0,b,yb,uhy,Π, p0, uf, P)
    @unpack r , β, θ, nx,ne = P;
    # ..................................................
    # Preliminaries
    vf0, D0, δ0, q0 = postVR(vr0,vd0,Π,r)
    evf0 = vf0*Π';
    evd0 = vd0*Π';
    qb   = q0 .* b;
    βevf0 = β*evf0;

    # ..................................................
    # Value and debt policy function update

    # Value of Default
    vd1 = uhy' + β*(θ*evf0[p0,:]'+(1-θ)*evd0);

    # Value of Repayment

    # Method 2: by column
    vr1 = Array{Float32,2}(undef, ne, nx);
    bopt = Array{CartesianIndex{2},2}(undef, ne, nx);
    upvr1!(vr1,bopt,yb,qb,βevf0,nx)
    return vr1, map(ii -> ii[1],bopt), vd1
end

function postVR(vr,vd,Π,r)
    vf = max.(vr,vd);
    D  = 1*(vd .> vr);
    δ  = D*Π';
    q  = (1/(1+r)) * (1 .- δ);
    return vf, D, δ, q;
end

function upvr1!(vr1,bopt,yb,qb,βevf0,nx)
    @fastmath @inbounds Threads.@threads for i in 1:nx
        vr1[:,i], bopt[:,i] = @views findmax(uf.(max.(0,yb[:,i] .- qb[:,i]')) .+ βevf0[:,i], dims=1);
    end
end
```

The master code is:

```
P = ( r = 0.017, σrisk = 2.0, ρ = 0.945, η = 0.025, β = 0.953,
        θ = 0.282,nx = 21, m = 3, μ = 0.0,fhat = 0.969,
        ub = 0, lb = -0.4, tol = 1e-6, maxite = 2000, ne = 251);
uf(x)  = -1/x;
hf(y::Array, fhat::Float64)  = min.(y, fhat * mean(y));
@time polfun, o2 = Solver(P,uf,hf);
```

The running tipe after first compilation is ~1 second. How can I speed-up this code? I am asking it because in previous versions of Matlab, in my experience, Julia was 10x faster but with the last version (Matlab 2020, that I tried last week) its performance was close to Julia but as I increase the number of grid-points (`ne > 1000`) Matlab reported faster. So I suppose that I am not taking advantage of all functionalities of Julia.

Note: The loop for `upvr1!` overperforms that a broadcasting version

```
yb = reshape(yb,(ne,nx,1));
βevf01 = PermutedDimsArray(reshape(βevf0,(ne,nx,1)),[3,2,1]);
qb1 = PermutedDimsArray(reshape(qb,(ne,nx,1)),[3,2,1]);
vr1, bopt = @views findmax(uf.(yb .- qb1) .+ βevf01, dims=3)
return vr1[:,:,1], map(ii -> ii[3], bopt)[:,:,1], vd1
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see what takes the longest here? I would highly recommend using `ProfileViews`